# Were single-sided floppy drives really more tolerant of rough handling?

Tags: history, hardware, portable, floppy-drive

The Osborne 1 was a luggable computer that contained a pair of 5.25-inch floppy drives. According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osborne_1

> Adam Osborne decided to use single-sided disk drives out of concern about double-sided drives suffering head damage from rough handling.

Is there a nonobvious reason why single-sided drives should be less vulnerable to this? Did other portable computers make the same design decision?

Comment: The technology was quite new at the moment.  He might have been overly cautious due to lack of usage data.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In a double-sided drive, there are two heads which are necessarily closely spaced, facing both sides of the thin magnetic-coated disc once it is inserted.  The concern would have been that the heads could collide with each other if the drive was jarred.

However, the drive designs I'm familiar with have a mechanism to hold the heads and drive spindle away from the disc until the drive door is closed (or, for the 3" and 3.5" *stiffies*, until the hard casing is detected in the inserted position).  This is to permit the disc to be inserted by an untrained user without damaging the disc, but it would also hold the heads apart from each other so that they could not collide.

If the drive were jarred with a disc inserted, the heads would collide with the disc surface - but that's also true of a single-sided drive.  I think floppy discs are a bit more tolerant of that than hard drives, mainly due to the lower speeds involved.

In practice, double-sided drives became common and did not have a reputation for fragility.  I have had several laptops (and even an 8088-based Amstrad luggable) with 3.5" double-sided drives, some of which had decidedly rough handling over the years but gave no trouble.

Comment: The problem with double sided drives are that when the heads collides with the surface, they also collides withe each others through the thin surface. This is what makes the damage. Floppies where disposable, and cheaper than one or two read/write heads (+someone changing them). In a single side drive the head would only crash into the soft floppy.

Comment: @UncleBod There needs to be some part on the opposite side to the head to give correct contact between floppy and head. I don't think you get reliable operation if there is just air on the other side.

Comment: The difference between single sided drives and double sided ones, where head collisions are concerned, is the double sided drives have the potential for the heads to collide with one another, pinching the disk surface between them.

Single sided drives typically have a pad on the non-active side, supported against the disk surface with a spring of some sort.

In the extreme, there really isn't a hard head collision case with single sided drives.

In my experience, there were no meaningful handling impact differences.  (I was rough on drives)

Comment: @Spud: Would there have been any difficulty constructing a drive so that each head would be placed to the left side of the access slot, viewed from its side, so that the heads weren't actually directly opposite?

Comment: @supercat  Other than a slightly more complicated transport mechanism, it's all just how the software works.  Well, that and each head would have to be done single sided style, with an additional pad and spring, right?

Comment: @Spud: I wouldn't think the mechanism would have to be more complicated, since the heads would be reading parts of the corresponding tracks on opposite sides of the disk.  They'd just be offset so one of them would be reading about 0.125" or so ahead of the other.

Comment: @supercat perhaps not. Maybe we will find out, should someone ever find a reason to reengineer the floppy. Would be fun to see.

Comment: @Spud: There are a number of magnetic-storage-related products from the 1980s that might be interesting to re-imagine.  The 300rpm of floppy drives, for example, seems designed to yield reasonable density at a bit rate that's slow enough to handle easily, but adding a fancier state machine for bit encoding and decoding and increasing the rotational speed would allow faster data storage and retrieval.

Comment: @Spud: I'm also curious about how Coleco's data storage tape system worked, and what would have been necessary to allow cassettes to be more convenient.  As a simple example, I would expect that for machines that use a custom cassette drive, doubling the motor speed could have cut loading times in half, with essentially no change in cost.

Comment: Ok, I gotta use the comment box.  (Was on mobile, sorry all.  I'm new, sheesh)

@supercat  Seems like some good questions!  The best tape system I used was on the CoCo.  6 bit DAC for output, fast CPU.  Custom code could exceed 2400 baud.  Had file names, seek capability.  Short tapes worked best.  Long tapes for finals and archives.  People may have a lot to contribute.

Comment: @supercat Doubling motor speed is something you could try.  Might have to tweak the bias, but otherwise, yeah.  Could work.  Worst case, one can simulate the tape circuit with a cheap micro and run some tests.

Comment: `I think floppy discs are a bit more tolerant of that than hard drives, mainly due to the lower speeds involved.` Floppy discs are designed around heads touching the platter, similar to how magnetic tape rubs across the heads in a player/recorder/drive. Hard drives are designed around them floating *above* the platter on a cushion of air.

Comment: @supercat (first comment): [Apple FileWare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_FileWare) drives (used on the Lisa and the very first Mac prototypes) were constructed in pretty much the way you describe, with the two sides' heads on opposite sides of the drive spindle, each opposed by its own pressure pad (this was done in an attempt to minimise head wear).  They were quickly withdrawn from service due to proving unreliable, but my sources don't say whether this was due to the unusual head configuration, or something else.